# Koa.js always get Not Found 404

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, koa, koa-router

I develop in Koa and I use Firebase to messaging, because of a real-time database. When I want to get messages from firebase I get Not found, but in `console.log()` it shows me.

This is my function to `getConversation`(Messages)

```
async getConversation(conversationName, callback) {
    var ref = await admin.database().ref(`messages/${conversationName}`)
    await ref.on('value', (snapshot, prevChildKey) => {
        var newPost = snapshot.val()
        let values = Object.values(newPost)
        callback(values)
    })
}
```

Then I call it in another controller like this

```
async getMessages(ctx) {
    const id = ctx.params.id

    const nameOfConversation = await ctx.db.Conversation.findById(id)

    await firebaseIndex.fbController.getConversation(nameOfConversation.name, response => {
        console.log(response)
        ctx.body = response //TODO
    })

}
```

At the last, I call it in routes.

```
router.get('/getConversation/:id', middlewares.isAuthenticate, controllers.userConversation.getMessages)
```

I always get body Not found.
Do anybody know how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

```
async getMessages(ctx) {
    const id = ctx.params.id

    const nameOfConversation = await ctx.db.Conversation.findById(id)

    ctx.body = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebaseIndex.fbController.getConversation(nameOfConversation.name, async response => {
            resolve(response)
        })
    })
}
```

`ctx.body` has to have a Promise.